# divide text into lines in binary image in matlab

Tags: matlab

please i need help dividing a binary image into lines
containing objects.
i have an image which contains text that i convert to binary,
i would like to have a matrix of the lines containing objects
so i can proceed to compare the objects and detect what kind of 
character each text is. 
my project is OCR(Optical Character Recognition).

Comment: the question is, 'is there a way to locate lines containing objects in binary codes so i can compare them?'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [bwlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwlabel.html).

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage);
```

This will give every object a unique number. You can get the coordinates of the objects by searching for it with `find` e.g. for '5':

```
[row col] = find(labeledImage==5);
```

I hope this helped a little.